# Email validation with Regex not working. ASP:NET MVC C# Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, validation, datatables, popup

- When I edit the data from my dataTable I want the email to be a valid email so I have to put an error validation when the user insert an invalid email format.
- In my controller I put the code to do that so when the user click save the error is display but when showing the error the data is saved  and It must be save only when the format is right.

I don't know how to make it work. I have to use regex. Also my regular expresion to validate the email is not very effective

My code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditData(ModelTemplateEmail modelEmail)
    {
        UpdateEmail(modelEmail.EmailId, modelEmail.userName, modelEmail.Title, 
                       modelEmail.Email,modelEmail.description, modelEmail.languageID);


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelEmail.userName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Please enter a user name");

        }

        else if (modelEmail.userName.Length > 20)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Please enter less than 20 characters");
        }



        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelEmail.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please enter an Email");
        }
        else if (!Regex.Match(modelEmail.Email, @"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$").Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {         
            return RedirectToAction("EmailData");
        };
        MainLanguagelist();

        return View ();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever validation fails , add an error is raised , you should return View to get back to the View from which error message would be displayed.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelEmail.Email))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please enter an Email");
    return View();
}
else if (!Regex.Match(modelEmail.Email, @"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$").Success)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please enter a valid email");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it returns to the view  but it save the data

Comment: oh i need to put that code befre the update. now its working. thanks!